# Video freezes every few seconds

Tags: video, nvidia, graphics, multimedia, freeze

I have problems playing videos on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine. The video **FREEZES** every 20-25 seconds, while I could still hear the audio. I use Totem Movie Player (GStreamer) & have nVidia on-board graphics card & AMD DualCore processor.

After some 5-10 seconds, the videos resume skipping the hung portion. But, I can hear the audio of that part! I've tried it with SMPlayer (GUI), VLC & Kaffeine. But, the same problem...

I recently **uninstalled** the nVidia drivers and since then, not even for a second, no video hung! So, I thought its the **problem with the proprietary nVidia drivers**. But, since its uninstalled, I'm not able to get the desired desktop resolution & effects. So, is there any way I can work it out?

Comment: I would check the situation out with another player. Eg `mplayer` is great, especially because it's mainly has CLI interface (though it has got GUI too). So try to use `mplayer` to play your video from terminal, and check the output of mplayer, what it prints there. Usually it gives more information you can use as diagnostics. I have multiple machines equipped with nVidia cards (but on-board ones) with the proprietary driver with a much weaker machine (old single core AMD CPU) but still, I haven't got this kind of problem. By the way, what happens after freeze? Does it continue after a while?

Comment: Yeah, after some 5-10 seconds, the videos resumes skipping the hung portion. But, I can hear the audio of that part!
I've tried it with SMPlayer (GUI), VLC & Kaffeine. But, the same problem...

Comment: I would suggest mplayer (command line version, from terminal) because you may see more related messages about the problem. You can also run command `top` in terminal while playing back to see if there is some kind of CPU-hungry happening during playback. I would also check the kernel log (or output of command `dmesg`), I had some kind of resource conflict in the past and kernel complained about it, which I could see at least ...

Comment: Did you check the temperature of the video card since you said it is onboard one. In many cases (At least for laptops) nvidia does not handle so well temperature, specially because of the space it has to cool off and the space it has for the heat it generates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found this problem addressed! I re-installed the nVidia drivers and the I disabled the "Sync to VBlank" option in CompizConfig Settings Manager (General > Display Options).
Thank you all :)

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar problems with HD videos. Under mplayer, vlc, smplayer, totem, etc. it would consume 100% CPU and choke the video.

I've used **good old xine** and it works perfectly, thou it's not very user friendly ;)